# Extract the capitalized letter sequence in a column and replace the column with the newly truncated string with str_extract in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following character vector that includes parentheses, periods, and unnecessary descriptive words

```
strings <- c("Poorly Graded Silty Sand (SP-SM).", "(Visual) Lean Clay (CL), with some sand.","Poorly Graded Silty Sand (SP-SM).","(Visual) Inorganic Silt (ML).","(Visual) Lean Clay (CL), with some sand.")
```

I wish to extract only the letter coding system that resides within the parenthesis on each line (ex: ML or SP-SM). Here is the desired vector.

```
need <- c("SP-SM", "CL","SP-SM","ML","CL")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround to match the opening parentheses followed by one or more upper case letters with `-`, followed by the closing parentheses

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(strings, "(?<=\\()[A-Z-]+(?=\\))")
[1] "SP-SM" "CL"    "SP-SM" "ML"    "CL"
```

Comment: Fantastic! Quick question, could you explain the structure of the str_extract pattern? Like what does the question mark do etc.?

Comment: @allencadbim1 it is a regex lookaround `(?<=\\()` that matcch the parentheses before the uppercase letters.  The idea is not to extract those parentheses by including it in lookaround

Answer (score 3):

This is the long version of akrun's solution:

```
str_extract(strings, '\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b\\-\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b|\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b')
```

output:

```
[1] "SP-SM" "CL"    "SP-SM" "ML"    "CL"
```

Explanation:

`[A-Z]{2}` Matches exactly two capital letters.

`\\-` Matches a hyphen.

`\\b` Matches between a word character and a non-word character.

`|` defines `OR`

Comment: Nice explanation my friend. I think `\\b` could be removed since it was explained once.

Comment: Thx dear @Anoushiravan. I updated.

Answer (score 1):

This could be another option in base R:

```
unlist(regmatches(strings, gregexpr("(?<=\\()[[:upper:]]{1,}(-[[:upper:]]{1,})?(?=\\))", strings, perl = TRUE)))

[1] "SP-SM" "CL"    "SP-SM" "ML"    "CL"
```

Note that I used optional string `?` for the second possible sub strings since it may not be there:
`(-[[:upper:]]{1,})?`

`(?<=\\()` positive lookbehind. It matches any string preceded by a parentheses `(`

`(?<=\\()` Positive lookahead. It matches any string followed by a parentheses `)`

`[[:upper:]]{1,}` It matches any more than 1 uppercase letter